# How to create a custom NumPy function?

Tags: python

this is the input:
import numpy as np
print(dir(np))
print(np.**version**)

this is the output:

['**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\python_project\untitled-17.py", line 3, in 
print(np.**version**)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '**version**'
PS D:\python_project>

i cant solve this problem

Comment: `np.__version__` you meant to use this

Comment: How does the question relate to the title *"How to create a custom NumPy function?"* ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you enclose your code with triple backticks like this:

```
Your code
```

The error might be an indentation error, so it will be easier to spot.

Next, to get the version, it's with double underscores around 'version' `np.__version__`

Finally, what are you trying to achieve with these two lines, what's your goal ?

When you run `dir(np)`, you get a list of attribute names such as variables, classes, and functions defined in the NumPy module.

Comment: Please do not post an answer to ask for clarification. This should have been a comment. I you don't have enough reputation to comment, then you need to gain some before ;-)